# Drupal 8 print fields inside view twig

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

In my content type with name "Banner" I have a field of type "Link" with "Machine name" = field_url_destinazione.

if I write this in my twig:

```
{% if content %}
    {{ content }}
{% endif %}
```

I see title, date and my field "field_url_destinazione"

I need to show only this field, there is a way?

i tried with:

```
{{ content.field_url_destinazione }}
{{ fields.field_url_destinazione }}
{{ field.field_url_destinazione }}
{{ field_url_destinazione }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first try

```
{{ content.field_url_destinazione }}
```

should definitely work. The only reason why it may not work is error in field name (or any other error in twig template).

---

As stated in [default node template](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21templates%21node.html.twig/8.4.x):

> - content: All node items. Use {{ content }} to print them all, or print a subset such as {{ content.field_example }}. Use {{ content|without('field_example') }} to temporarily suppress the printing of a given child element.